# Angular table-sort and drag and drop table row conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, tablesort

I am using [angular table-sort](https://github.com/mattiash/angular-tablesort) and [angular drag-drop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop) in my project. When I am dragging a row and trying to drop it to another row, then table sort forcefully sort the rows to their previous position.

If I remove the table sort directive `ts-repeat`, then drag and drop works perfectly. I also need default table column sorting **"Age"** ascending. I have made an example on plunker for better understanding. [https://plnkr.co/edit/pHlTufpayFAB4he8bN6y](https://plnkr.co/edit/pHlTufpayFAB4he8bN6y?p=preview)

So, how to prevent table-sort when drag and dropping a row?

Can anyone help me solving this issue? I would really appreciate this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should just get rid of `ts-repeat`, and only sort the data initially (in your service/controller). It's not a bug, it's a feature. Imagine, that you remove and then re-add an element to a table, which is sorted. You want it to keep sorted, right?

Comment: But I need `ts-repeat` too. Because it's a client requirement to sort data initially, then sort with different columns if they want. So, for this, using `ts-repeat` is mandatory for me. And when adding a new row, it's also been sorted in my project (didn't include it for simplicity).

So, I've to use both `ts-repeat` and `drag-and-drop` in the same table.

Comment: Now I get it, you want to be able to sort, but also modify the order manually. I think you could try http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/, it's a bit more feature rich. I guess you can turn off the sorting if manual changes were made.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by using [Angular ui-sortable](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/) instead of angular drag-drop. I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG Table offers row reordering with drag drop, you need upcoming 5.2.1 though.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/reorder